# How to use manually built opencv in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, opencv

I just built Opencv using CMake to enable CUDA support in a folder *Downloads/CVCuda/build*

After configuring and generating the build in the above folder, I built and installed it using VS 2019. How do I use this library in one of my virtual environments? Also, do the above followed steps install the opencv library in the global python environment?

I am very new to manually built packages and would really appreciate your help!